# creating MAC like QSlider

Tags: qt, qslider

I want to make the default QSlider like that of Macintosh. Is it possible. I tried with the setStyleSheet, but failed to make that one.

Any suggestions... Please?

Comment: Can you add an image of what you are looking for? I don't have a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

The appearance of a QSlider depends on the style your Qt application is using. If you're running a Mac, it should use a Mac-like style out of the box. If it doesn't, you can force it from the command line by passing an "-style macintosh" or programmatically using [QApplication::setStyle()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qapplication.html#setStyle).

You can't get Mac-looking widgets in a non-Mac environment as the implementation uses the native toolkit to draw widgets.

Comment: Well I have been trying with the Qt QSlider:etStyleSheet option. But failed...Any tips how to use QSlider:setStyleSheet to create MAc like QSlider. I just want to change the QSlider handle i.e. the pointer rounded. Is it possible in any ways?

Comment: In addition, you can define your own style that draws things how you want, and install it.  It is more difficult, but made easier by inheriting from one of the provided styles and only changing the drawing for the elements you want changed.